# How to access Nattable ViewportLayer scrollbar?

Tags: nattable

I'd like to put a custom listener on the scrollbar of the viewport layer to trigger other code whenever the scrollbar is moved. I currently extended the HorizontalScrollBarHandler and overrode the handleEvent() method. The handler needs to take in the scrollbar from the ViewportLayer, but unfortunately it's private and has no getter method. Is there any other way that I can access the scrollbar to use with my custom handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NatTable` is a `Canvas` which is a `Scrollable`. So actually you should not try to do deal with internals. It should be possible to call `natTable.getVerticalBar()` and `natTable.getHorizontalBar()` to register your listener.

Alternatively you could implement your own IScroller as explained here: http://blog.vogella.com/2015/01/26/nattable-with-custom-scrollbars/

But just for adding a listener it should be sufficient to use default SWT mechanisms.